# Running an Exe in Docker Giving Permission denied Error

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

We have a .net core web api.

we have following code in one of the controller.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("/app/files/test.exe")
                {
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };
                var p = new Process()
                {
                    StartInfo = psi
                };

                p.Start();
```

When we call the api controller, It is giving the error Permission denied.

Please help.

Comment: Share your dockerfile and be sure you are creating /files/ directory in your container.

Comment: Check if you're running a Windows or a Linux container. Since you're trying to run an .exe file, you probably need to run in a Windows container. Most .NET Docker guides and tutorials on the net show how to create a Linux container which probably can't run your .exe file.